# Copy value from a dictionary to dictionary rather than address

Tags: c#, dictionary, value-type, reference-type

I'm attempting to copy values from one dictionary to another, so when that value is changed in the new dictionary it does not change the old value. Right now I believe I am copying the address instead.

```
 public Cube Right(Cube cube) {
        Dictionary<SidePosition, Side> newSides = new Dictionary<SidePosition, Side>(cube.Sides);

        for (int i = 0;  i < RightSideOrder.Count; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < RightFaceOrder.Count; j++) {
                newSides[RightSideOrder[i]].Faces[RightFaceOrder[j]] =
                    cube.Sides[RightSideOrder[GetAntecedantSideIndex(i)]]
                    .Faces[RightFaceOrder[j]];
            }
        }
        return cube;
    }

    private int GetAntecedantSideIndex(int currentIndex) {
        if (currentIndex == 0)
            return 3;
        return currentIndex - 1;
    }
}
```

Both `Cube` and the values contained inside it's Dictionary of `Side` are structs. I'm very new to C# so apologies if naming convention is off.

From my research/speaking to people the solution could involve an ICloneable or a new IDictionary implementation but no luck has been had so far with either or these.

The full project can be found here if more details are needed: https://github.com/Gregam3/RubicksCubeSolver

The code Excerpt is from a class called CubeManipulator

TLDR; how do I get a value from a Dictionary as a value type

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that I could copy and paste into a console app to repro the issue.

Comment: two ideas worth to remember: 1. deep copy (answer below)  2. immutable objects (if possible, many algoriths are simpler and safer)

Answer (score 0):

Following this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can use deep copy operation

> when a deep copy operation is performed, the cloned Person object,
>   including its Person.IdInfo property, can be modified without
>   affecting the original object.

Something like:

```
public class SidePosition
{
    public IdInfo IdInfo;

    public SidePosition DeepCopy()
    {
       SidePosition other = (SidePosition) this.MemberwiseClone();
       other.IdInfo= new IdInfo(IdInfo.IdNumber);
       return other;
    }
}

public class Side
{
    public IdInfo IdInfo;

    public Side DeepCopy()
    {
       Side other = (Side) this.MemberwiseClone();
       other.IdInfo= new IdInfo(IdInfo.IdNumber);
       return other;
    }
}

public Cube Right(Cube cube) {
        Dictionary<SidePosition, Side> newSides = new Dictionary<SidePosition, Side>();
        foreach(var item in cube.Sides)
           newSides.Add(new SidePosition(item.key), new Side(item.value));

        //your logic
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

View the below link to see an example of making a copy of a dictionary so changing values in one dictinoary does not affect another after the copy:

[Example of making a copy of a dictionary](https://www.dotnetperls.com/copy-dictionary)